# Can't figure out the error with 'updateProfile' in my flutter code

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

From the following code i don't know what to do with 'updateProfile' error

```
  signUp() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();

      try {
        UserCredential user = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _email, password: _password);
        if (user != null) {
          [updateProfile][1] updateuser = await _auth.updateProfile();
          updateuser.displayName = _name;
          user.updateProfile();
        }
      } catch (e) {
        showError(e.message);
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
UserCredential user = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _email, password: _password);
```

You call the variable 'user' but you set it to UserCredential. `updateProfile()` is not a function of [UserCredential](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserCredential-class.html). `updateProfile()` is not a method of [FirebaseAuth](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html) either.

Obtain user like this:

`User user = (await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)).user;`